# How to set WPF ScrollViewer height dynamically?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, scrollviewer

I have the following test sample:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfScrollTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Content="Text to mess up the scrollview"/>
                <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" Content="Button"/>
                        <Button MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" Content="Button"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Which creates this:

[image: Scrollbar bottom missing]

My question is how do I set the `ScrollViewer.Height` dynamically while still being able to see the bottom of the scrollbar?  In my sample, the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer` is too long because of the `Label` above it ..

I don't want to fix the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer`to a static value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to remove the outer StackPanel to a Grid, since Stackpanel wont respect the children size. And remove the ScrollViewer.Height binding. Now you just need to create two RowDefinition for the Grid and place the Label to Grid.Row=0 and ScrollViwer to Grid.Row=1.

Code is below. So my tip here is, use StackPanel/Canvas only if necessary and may be for the inner levels. Try to use Grid more to get very dynamic layouts.

```
  <Border>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Content="Text to mess up the scrollview"/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Button MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" Content="Button"/>
                <Button MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" Content="Button"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: hey , that works. I see now that because the RowDefinition for the ScrollViewer is *, so it has a defined size and thus works. Thanks :)